# How do I fix unexpected end of file in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I had much luck last time I submitted a question so here goes:  I am trying to debug a somewhat large BASH script when I get the following error:

```
./test.sh: line 418: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
./test.sh: line 427: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

The code below starts at line 400:

```
    echo "###########################################################"
    echo
;;
4)
    culebra_carriers
    get_month
    get_day
    logs_cdrs
    logs_wap
    get_mdn

    echo
    echo "###########################################################"
    echo
    echo "Searching for activity of $mobileNumber on $MON $DAY......."
    echo
    zgrep $mobileNumber $HOME/culebrapeak/$LOGCDR/$CULEB/$MON/$WAPLOG
    echo
    echo "###########################################################"
    echo
;;
esac
done
}

clear
main_menu
```

How do I make this error go away?  It looks like I have the double quotes in all the right places... but this is only my 4th or 5th bash script... so please go easy on me.

Comment: The portion you've quoted seems correct - chances are the missing quote is earlier in the file. Mismatched quotes tend to cause errors that don't necessarily get detected near where they occur.

Comment: The problem is above the code you posted. Look for mismatched quotes. And quote your variables. And use a little bit more indentation.

Comment: Thanks to @twalberg and dennis williamson for your efforts.  My vi editor has everything in nice colored sections and usually the colors are out of whack when there is a little error like this.  Now begins the search for a needle in my haystack...  Sorry dennis, this website wouldn't let me shout out to you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was, indeed, missing a double quote at the top of my script.  Thanks to all for the help!

Comment: You've made a mistake here by submitting your own answer, then accepting it as "the" answer... when Anthony gave you a pretty good answer.  
(You may be unfamiliar with StackOverFlow rules, but Anthony gets a deserved credit/thanks if you had accepted his answer)

Answer (score 2):

A good way to solve problems like this is to use a text editor that highlights code between quotes. Short of that, if the "find" feature of your text editor gives a count too, you may be able to use it to quantitatively detect start/end character symmetry problems. The highlighting from the find feature will aide your eye tremedously.